# jQuery get content of a div and make it a class of its parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the content of `.getClass` (white, blue etc) and add it as a class for its parent li tag?

I have the following html structure:

```html
<div class="main">
   <ul>
    <li class="even">
         <div class="content">
           <div class="getClass">white</div>
         </div>
     </li>
     <li class="odd">
         <div class="content">
           <div class="getClass">red</div>
         </div>
     </li>
     <li class="even">
         <div class="content">
           <div class="getClass">blue</div>
         </div>
     </li>
     <li class="odd">
         <div class="content">
           <div class="getClass">black</div>
         </div>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've come up with this:

```
var str = $( ".getClass" ).text();
```

What's next?

Cheers

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: welll...i tried to store the content into a var but I don t know how to make it a class of the parent.
var str = $( "#getClass" ).text();

Comment: Then google maybe?

Comment: Instead using id="getClass" you should set a specific class to these elements (e.g. class="get-class"). ID should be unique in your whole document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the elements you want to modify, use `.each` to create a loop, then use `.text()` to get the content of each element:

```
$('li').each(function (i, el) {
    var className = $(el).find('#getClass').text();
    $(el).addClass(className)
});
```

But your code is actually invalid HTML, you have duplicate `id` attributes. So use classes instead, you almost never need `id`

Comment: Thanks...that  worked.I the real code i do have classes but i just copied the wrong li and duplicated here.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly your HTML is invalid. You cannot have multiple elements with the same `id` in the document. You should use a `class` to group elements instead. From there you can select the `li` elements and provide the `addClass()` method with a function to return the required string generated from the `text()` of the child element. Try this:

```
$('li').addClass(function() {
  return $(this).find('.getClass').text().trim();
});
```

```js
$('li').addClass(function() {
  return $(this).find('.getClass').text().trim();
});
```

```css
.white {
  color: #CCC;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
.black {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <ul>
    <li class="even">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="getClass">white</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="odd">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="getClass">red</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="even">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="getClass">blue</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="odd">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="getClass">black</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome solution! You don't need the `.trim()` though

Comment: @bfred.it true in this case. Although I prefer using it on `text()` as you never know what whitespace will be thrown in.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this using jQuery methods [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)